# What's the difference between 'in the year' and 'of the year'?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

1. the coldest month **of** the year
2. the coldest month **in** the year

To my ears 'the coldest month **of** the year' sounds more natural than 'the coldest month **in** the year'. Is there a difference in meaning and/or usage? Is 'in the year' even grammatically sound in such a context?

Comment: Either one's probably going to do what you want.

Comment: *Months of the year* and *days of the week* are commoner and more natural expressions than *months in the year* and *days in the week*.[https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=months+of+the+year%2Cmonths+in+a+year%2C+days+of+the+week%2C+days+in+a+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmonths%20of%20the%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmonths%20in%20a%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdays%20of%20the%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdays%20in%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0]

Comment: “The coldest month of the year” seems to be just as good as “the tallest person in the family”  or  “the fastest car in the garage.”